# docker-compose: Compose file "..." is invalid because: unsupported config options

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have recently pulled an [official repository](https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose) from docker consisting of docker-compose templates.

When I try to build and run ***nginx-golang-mysql/docker-compose.yml*** with ***docker-compose up -d*** I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for volumes: 'db-data'
Unsupported config option for secrets: 'db-password'
Unsupported config option for services: 'proxy'
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file ([original available on github](https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/blob/master/nginx-golang-mysql/docker-compose.yaml)):

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    build: backend
    secrets:
      - db-password
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
  db:
    # We use a mariadb image which supports both amd64 & arm64 architecture
    image: mariadb:10.6.4-focal
    # If you really want to use MySQL, uncomment the following line
    #image: mysql:8.0.27
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "127.0.0.1", "--silent"]
      interval: 3s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    secrets:
      - db-password
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=example
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db-password
    expose:
      - 3306
  proxy:
    build: proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on: 
      - backend
volumes:
  db-data:
secrets:
  db-password:
    file: db/password.txt
```

These are my versions of `docker` and `docker-compose`:

```
Docker version 20.10.13, build a224086
docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown
```

Any idea why I'm getting these errors? The other compose-files throw a similar error when I try to run them. I'm using this version of Docker and docker-compose for other projects successfully on a daily basis.

Comment: You are using a docker-compose syntax which is unsupported by your docker-compose version. Upgrade your docker-compose binary to the latest available => `pip install --upgrade docker-compose`. [Your example file validates without any problems in docker-compose v1.29.2](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/c16774a843cae22e3647bc9052fb8e5b)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Zeitounator's comment:

The problem was I have installed docker-compose from apt and not from the official repository. The apt only had 1.25 version and I believed it was the latest. In fact the latest is 1.29 at the moment. After installing the latest version [as shown](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) in the official docs it now works.

The `pip install --upgrade docker-compose` didn't update it for me. I had to remove the version installed with apt and install it again from the official docker repo.

Answer (score 0):

[Compose file version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) requires a `version:` label; see [About versions and upgrading](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#versioning).  You need to add this line, usually at the start of the file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
```

Absent this line, `docker-compose` interprets the file as a [version 1 Compose file](https://web.archive.org/web/20210302145052/https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/).  This omits the top-level `services:` key and puts all services at the top level of the file, but it also does not support `volumes:` or `networks:`, and modern Docker networking doesn't work with a v1 Compose file.

An argument could be made that the newer [Compose Specification](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md) makes [`version:` optional](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#version-top-level-element).  However, removing it makes the file incompatible with existing tooling, as you've seen in this question, and I would always include it.

Comment: This was the first thing I've tried and it still threw back a slightly different Compose file is invalid error. I have tried every major versions even 2.x and it was the same. The only way I could make the compose file work with the incorrect (1.25.0) version is to comment the parts it had problem with. It works fine now with the latest version of docker-compose (1.29.2)